# How to set function to true/false on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make the navbar slide down on scroll up, and stay fixed when #menu-bar is clicked. But I don't know how to change the value back to false on autohide when I click the same button again, just when I have two buttons. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
$(function () {
'use strict';

var autohide = $('.navbar').bootstrapAutoHideNavbar({
    disableAutoHide: false
});

$('#menu-bar').click(function () {
    autohide.setDisableAutoHide(true);
});
$('#menu-close').click(function () {
    autohide.setDisableAutoHide(false);
 });
});
```

Comment: You need to reference the current state, either by accessing it via a getter, or store your own variable elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure what you mean. I tried to use attr to change ID so that it changes to #menu-close after click, but it seems disable autohide is still true?

Comment: `$('#menu-bar').click(function () {` check the state (visible/hidden) here with an if/else. Within the if/else call `autohide.setDisableAutoHide()` passing it  true or false, depending on what you're checking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use another variable to set the value disableAutoHide like so maybe :

```
$(function () {
'use strict';

var disableAutoHideValue = false;
var autohide = $('.navbar').bootstrapAutoHideNavbar({
    disableAutoHide: false
});

$('#menu-bar').click(function () {
    disableAutoHideValue = ! disableAutoHideValue;
    autohide.setDisableAutoHide(disableAutoHideValue);
});
$('#menu-close').click(function () {
    autohide.setDisableAutoHide(false);
 });
});
```

Tell me if it works !

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! Even without #menu-close ID, not sure why, is it because "!" ?. I removed the id trying with if/else as suggested above, but couldn't get it to work so forgot to put it back before I tried your code.

Comment: Great ! Glad I could help :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as resolved if your issue is closed.